# When I run any App the program gives me a error

Tags: java, android

When I run any app,even the basic one where it has  the "Hello world" on the screen doesn't work. can someone help me figure out what this all means >.> thank you kindly. this happens on my computer, on a friends computer it simply won't run, I have freshly re installed android studio (but not the java JDKs)

```js
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
unknown output extension: C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Spellbook\SpellbookD
usage:
dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
[--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
[--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
unknown output extension: C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Spellbook\SpellbookD
usage:
dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
[--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
[--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
[--num-threads=<n>] [--incremental] [--force-jumbo]
[--multi-dex [--main-dex-list=<file> [--minimal-main-dex]]
[<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] ...
Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
jar/zip. Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk or be a directory.
Positions options: none, important, lines.
--multi-dex: allows to generate several dex files if needed. This option is
exclusive with --incremental, causes --num-threads to be ignored and only
supports folder or archive output.
--main-dex-list=<file>: <file> is a list of class file names, classes defined by
those class files are put in classes.dex.
--minimal-main-dex: only classes selected by --main-dex-list are to be put in
the main dex.
dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
[--print=<print types>]
dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
[--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
[--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
dx --find-usages <file.dex> <declaring type> <member>
Find references and declarations to a field or method.
declaring type: a class name in internal form, like Ljava/lang/Object;
member: a field or method name, like hashCode
dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
dx --version
Print the version of this tool (1.8).
dx --help
Print this message.
[--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
[--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
[--num-threads=<n>] [--incremental] [--force-jumbo]
[--multi-dex [--main-dex-list=<file> [--minimal-main-dex]]
[<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] ...
Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
jar/zip. Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk or be a directory.
Positions options: none, important, lines.
--multi-dex: allows to generate several dex files if needed. This option is
exclusive with --incremental, causes --num-threads to be ignored and only
supports folder or archive output.
--main-dex-list=<file>: <file> is a list of class file names, classes defined by
those class files are put in classes.dex.
--minimal-main-dex: only classes selected by --main-dex-list are to be put in
the main dex.
dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
[--print=<print types>]
dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
[--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
[--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
dx --find-usages <file.dex> <declaring type> <member>
Find references and declarations to a field or method.
declaring type: a class name in internal form, like Ljava/lang/Object;
member: a field or method name, like hashCode
dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
dx --version
Print the version of this tool (1.8).
dx --help
Print this message.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Spellbook\SpellbookD&D5th\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-20.0.0-0d853c27bd4d6b62d50991a94f330ee92c9660ea.jar C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\20.0.0\support-annotations-20.0.0.jar
Error Code:
1
Output:
unknown output extension: C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Spellbook\SpellbookD
usage:
dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
[--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
[--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
[--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
[--num-threads=<n>] [--incremental] [--force-jumbo]
[--multi-dex [--main-dex-list=<file> [--minimal-main-dex]]
[<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] ...
Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
jar/zip. Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk or be a directory.
Positions options: none, important, lines.
--multi-dex: allows to generate several dex files if needed. This option is
exclusive with --incremental, causes --num-threads to be ignored and only
supports folder or archive output.
--main-dex-list=<file>: <file> is a list of class file names, classes defined by
those class files are put in classes.dex.
--minimal-main-dex: only classes selected by --main-dex-list are to be put in
the main dex.
dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
[--print=<print types>]
dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
[--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
[--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
dx --find-usages <file.dex> <declaring type> <member>
Find references and declarations to a field or method.
declaring type: a class name in internal form, like Ljava/lang/Object;
member: a field or method name, like hashCode
dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
dx --version
Print the version of this tool (1.8).
dx --help
Print this message.
The system cannot find the path specified.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 23.0 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:preDexDebug
unknown output extension: C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Spellbook\SpellbookD
usage:
dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
[--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
[--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
[--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
[--num-threads=<n>] [--incremental] [--force-jumbo]
[--multi-dex [--main-dex-list=<file> [--minimal-main-dex]]
[<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] ...
Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
jar/zip. Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk or be a directory.
Positions options: none, important, lines.
--multi-dex: allows to generate several dex files if needed. This option is
exclusive with --incremental, causes --num-threads to be ignored and only
supports folder or archive output.
--main-dex-list=<file>: <file> is a list of class file names, classes defined by
those class files are put in classes.dex.
--minimal-main-dex: only classes selected by --main-dex-list are to be put in
the main dex.
dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
[--print=<print types>]
dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
[--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
[--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
dx --find-usages <file.dex> <declaring type> <member>
Find references and declarations to a field or method.
declaring type: a class name in internal form, like Ljava/lang/Object;
member: a field or method name, like hashCode
dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
dx --version
Print the version of this tool (1.8).
dx --help
unknown output extension: C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Spellbook\SpellbookD
usage:
dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
[--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
[--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
[--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
[--num-threads=<n>] [--incremental] [--force-jumbo]
[--multi-dex [--main-dex-list=<file> [--minimal-main-dex]]
[<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] ...
Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
jar/zip. Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk or be a directory.
Positions options: none, important, lines.
--multi-dex: allows to generate several dex files if needed. This option is
exclusive with --incremental, causes --num-threads to be ignored and only
supports folder or archive output.
--main-dex-list=<file>: <file> is a list of class file names, classes defined by
those class files are put in classes.dex.
--minimal-main-dex: only classes selected by --main-dex-list are to be put in
the main dex.
dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
[--print=<print types>]
dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
[--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
[--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
dx --find-usages <file.dex> <declaring type> <member>
Find references and declarations to a field or method.
declaring type: a class name in internal form, like Ljava/lang/Object;
member: a field or method name, like hashCode
dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
dx --version
Print the version of this tool (1.8).
dx --help
Print this message.
Print this message.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
FAILED
The system cannot find the path specified.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Spellbook\SpellbookD&D5th\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-cb3d2cfea94b9f5266afe2f7149823e33a7f9188.jar C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Spellbook\SpellbookD&D5th\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\classes.jar
Error Code:
1
Output:
unknown output extension: C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Spellbook\SpellbookD
usage:
dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
[--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
[--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
[--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
[--num-threads=<n>] [--incremental] [--force-jumbo]
[--multi-dex [--main-dex-list=<file> [--minimal-main-dex]]
[<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] ...
Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
jar/zip. Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk or be a directory.
Positions options: none, important, lines.
--multi-dex: allows to generate several dex files if needed. This option is
exclusive with --incremental, causes --num-threads to be ignored and only
supports folder or archive output.
--main-dex-list=<file>: <file> is a list of class file names, classes defined by
those class files are put in classes.dex.
--minimal-main-dex: only classes selected by --main-dex-list are to be put in
the main dex.
dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
[--print=<print types>]
dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
[--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
[--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
dx --find-usages <file.dex> <declaring type> <member>
Find references and declarations to a field or method.
declaring type: a class name in internal form, like Ljava/lang/Object;
member: a field or method name, like hashCode
dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
dx --version
Print the version of this tool (1.8).
dx --help
Print this message.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Build tools version? SDK version? Gradle version? Gradle build scripts? Any relative code?

Comment: I'm using the emulator on my Computer.

Answer (score 0):

check the sdk path and other properties in project properties menu.

SDK path should be give correctly.

if you recently done upgrading it may also effect. check once.

And check the res file once. if there is any error the build not successful.

If everything seems correctly, then clean the project. And run again

Comment: I did make a path into the JDK like the instalation instructions,can you guys help me how to check the sdk path and the res file please.